# Converting a data frame into tables with indexes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
array = {'name': ['John', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'John'], 'color': ['Green', 'Black', 'Blue', 'Black']}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df
```

It looks like this:

```
    name    color
0   John    Green
1   Rob     Black
2   Rob     Blue
3   John    Black
```

I am looking for a way to create three separate tables or data frames:

Main:

```
    name    color
0    1       1
1    2       2
2    2       3
3    1       2
```

Names:

```
        name
   1    John
   2    Rob
```

Colors:

```
        color
   1    Green
   2    Black
   3    Blue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with unique values and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
a1, b1 = pd.factorize(df['color'].unique())
colors = pd.DataFrame({'color':b1}, index=a1+1)
print (colors)
   color
1  Green
2  Black
3   Blue

a2, b2 = pd.factorize(df['name'].unique())
names = pd.DataFrame({'name':b2}, index=a2+1)
print (names)
   name
1  John
2   Rob

main = df.copy()
main['name'] = main['name'].map(dict(zip(b2, a2+1)))
main['color'] = main['color'].map(dict(zip(b1, a1+1)))
print (main)
   name  color
0     1      1
1     2      2
2     2      3
3     1      2
```

Comment: In my full dataframe, the factorize command gives me: 'ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1807, 1), indices imply (1808, 1)'. Any ideas what can cause such an error?

Comment: @gromer Maybe missing values?

Comment: no. It is derived from a DF with no nulls

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) Pandas type.

### The simplest way if you are OK with different category codes than the ones in your question

*Note: The Pandas category type is indexing from 0 and categories are getting those codes based on order*

Cast a Pandas object to the category type:

```
df = df.astype("category")
```

Get codes for every category:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)

Out:
   name  color
0     0      2
1     1      0
2     1      1
3     0      0
```

Get names and colors:

```
df["name"].cat.categories.to_frame(index=False, name="name")

Out:
    name
0   John
1   Rob
```

and

```
df["color"].cat.categories.to_frame(index=False, name="color")

Out:
    color
0   Black
1   Blue
2   Green
```

### If you want to use the category codes from the question indexed from 1

*Note: This is not ideal when you have a lot of categories where you want to define a custom order, because you will have to always set the order; see below. But it might be solved with some utility function according to your needs.*

You can use [pd.CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html).

Set dtypes (with the preferred category order):

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

df.name = df.name.astype(CategoricalDtype(["John", "Rob"]))
df.color = df.color.astype(CategoricalDtype(["Green", "Black", "Blue"]))
```

Get codes ("+1" because we want to index from 1, not 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes + 1)

Out:
   name  color
0     1      1
1     2      2
2     2      3
3     1      2
```

Get names and colors:

```
categories = df["name"].cat.categories
pd.DataFrame({"name": categories}, index=pd.RangeIndex(1, len(categories) + 1))

Out:
    name
1   John
2   Rob
```

and

```
categories = df["color"].cat.categories
pd.DataFrame({"color": categories}, index=pd.RangeIndex(1, len(categories) + 1))

Out:
    color
1   Green
2   Black
3   Blue
```